# Did Harvey Dent know that it was Bruce Wayne who locked him up?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dark-knight

In The Dark Knight's fundraiser scene where Bruce Wayne invites many people for Harvey's fundraiser, Joker attacks the place with his goons, looking for Harvey. When Bruce sees this, he catches Harvey from the back and locks him up in a safe room.

When he is dragging Harvey, Rachel says in a surprising manner "What are you doing?" and Harvey was not unconcious at that time. So clearly Harvey knows that Rachel knows, who locked him up.

After this we don't get to know how Harvey felt about the incident.
What was he told? Did he know that it was Bruce who locked him up or did he think that it was Batman? If he knew that it was Bruce Wayne, how come he had no questions about that, because it was a very unusual act from Bruce Wayne.

Comment: And what would *Rachel* have said if it had been a random guy that knocked down *Harvey*? *"What are you doing, guy that I've never seen before?"*?

Comment: @ChristianRau with all due respect, if possible, please see the scene again, may be u will understand what I am trying to say.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Being choked unconscious can result in short term memory loss. It is likely that Harvey Dent may not remember Rachel asking or the question. Or the assault. Choking someone out doesn't knock them out for very long either. It is possible Batman drugged Dent inside the panic room and then took him home later and he woke up in his own bed.

Answer (score 6):

He used his Batman voice to tell Rachel about the Joker coming and Dent had his back facing Bruce the whole time before he fell unconscious, so he didn't hear Bruce's real voice or see his face the entire time making it likely that Dent thought it was Batman.